# Code Analysis settings for windows phone project not compatible

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, code-analysis

My company develops a quite extensive .net application, consisting of multiple projects, all hosted on a Team Foundation Server. I'm currently working on a companion app (Windows Phone 8.1, c# and XAML), which is quite small, has it's own solution but also is part of the VCS. When I try to check in, Visual Studio 2015 gives me a policy warning:

> The Code Analysis settings for one or more projects are not compatible with Code Analysis policy.

On Double-clicking that message, it lists several rules which it claims are not present in the project settings (Including a dubious "rule 0"). The thing is, in the Project Settings I've set up the Code Analysis to use the same Rule Set the rest of the application is using. And this rule set, when I open it, does actually contain the rules that VS claims are not present in the settings (except for that rule 0). I'm stuck here, any suggestions at what could be going wrong or what else I could try would be greatly appreciated.

(And yes, I know I can override the warning, but I'd actually like to get the Code Analysis working.)

EDIT: I've checked the Release and Debug configurations. We even have separate rule sets for the two configurations, but they both seem to be set up correctly.

Comment: I see that on occasion, but normally goes away with a rebulid

Comment: the project section is also debug / release specific so that could be worth checking too

Comment: Rebuild doesn't help.
I'm only working in debug at the moment, but I've also checked the release configuration. We actually have separate rule sets for both configurations, which are set up correctly as far as I can see.

Comment: The only other thing thats helped me in the past with wierd policy errors is: Close Studio > Delete SUO > Open Studio. In vs2015 the suo is in the .vs folder.

Comment: Just tried that, did not help either... :/

Comment: Well at first it didn't work, the warning still came, but a while later it worked... I'm confused. I hope that was just a temporary issue.

Comment: grad it's sorted :-) Are any of my comments worth my time converting int an answer?

Comment: Well, the restart studio and delete suo-file is the one that probably did the trick, so if you'd covert it to an answer I'd choose it as best answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I had to actually build the **release** configuration and check in with that build active.

It went back to not working again after the other answer temporarily worked, and going over this in detail with a colleague, he finally pointed that out to me, that usually the check-in should happen with the release build, not the debug one.

Visual Studio was incredibly unhelpful with its error messages about this, and I'm still not sure why I was temporarily able to check in with the debug build, but it's now up and running fine.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that can help with weird policy errors when everything is configured ok with regards to Debug / Release rulesets, and where a rebuild doesn't clear it is to delete the suo file. 
(This is the [Solution User Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165909.aspx) file).

**Steps:**

- Close Studio
- Delete the SUO (for Visual Studio 2015, this is in the .vs folder)
- Reopen Studio

Comment: So it went back to not working again after worked at first, but I got it working now - see my other answer. Sorry I have to undo the accepted answer again.